# Trouble finding LHOST and which IP address to use?

Tags: social-engineering, pdf

I'm currently using the social engineering toolkit (SET) and I'm generating a malicious PDF file. One of the first things SET asks me after choosing a File-format exploit is the IP address for the reverse connection. In this case, would I want to use my private IP address or my public IP address?

After going further down through the steps and choosing a Windows meterpreter reverse_tcp it will ask for the IP address for the payload listener (LHOST). The only trouble is I'm having trouble finding out exactly what my LHOST is.

Comment: Have a  look at this: https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2014/01/04/metasploit-meterpreter-and-nat/

Comment: Yes, these are basic questions, and they are not security questions but networking questions. Put aside the fact that you want to use SET, and think only about a random computer out there needing to connect to the machine with SET on it. What networking needs to be in place to allow that incoming connection to work? Once you figure that out (and understand it), then you will have your answers. Topics: private/public IP addresses, port forwarding, NAT, proxies.